# Find and Replace both not working after updating to Android Studio 4.2

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-4.2

I have a Mac. Just updated to 4.2 and now Find and Replace both don't work. The keyboard shortcuts as well as the Edit>Find>Find... and Replace... menu options not working. I click them and nothing opens, nothing happens. I changed the keymap to MacOS to no avail.

Find in Path and Replace in Path shortcuts and menu options both work.

Any help?

(Just updated Flutter as well but can't see that changing anything.)

EDIT:

Here is what gets recorded in the log when I try to use Find. The last line appears to be an error.

```
at com.intellij.find.SearchReplaceComponent.<init>(SearchReplaceComponent.java:201)
at com.intellij.find.SearchReplaceComponent.<init>(SearchReplaceComponent.java:50)
at com.intellij.find.SearchReplaceComponent$Builder.build(SearchReplaceComponent.java:697)
at com.intellij.find.EditorSearchSession.<init>(EditorSearchSession.java:118)
at com.intellij.find.EditorSearchSession.start(EditorSearchSession.java:260)
at com.intellij.openapi.editor.actions.IncrementalFindAction$Handler.doExecute(IncrementalFindAction.java:67)
2021-05-10 17:03:07,095 [  85136]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: Find
```

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show log in...")?

Comment: Yes. I will edit my question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding a [discussion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249809?_ga=2.260793357.1261235730.1620680828-2099587976.1620680828#focus=Comments-27-4440190.0-0) of a similar problem for IntelliJ (same error message) I tried this workaround.

I went to `~Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/options/other.xml` and searched FindSplitterProportion.

Original was:

```
<property name="FindSplitterProportion" value="1.0360656" />
```

Replaced it with:

```
<property name="FindSplitterProportion" value="0.2" />.
```

Find and Replace both seem to work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved my life!!, I am using windows and the path of the other.xml is at C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.2\options